# How to configure OSPF to create desired routing paths?

Tags: routing, ospf, pbr, asymmetric-routing

Is there any way to assign OSPF cost so that when is traceroute 147.147.11.98 from R1

it goes like R1->R4->R5->R2

and when I traceroute 147.147.11.98 from R5

it goes like R5->R4->R1->R3->R2

[image]

I tried to set ospf cost but only work either for R1 or R5, instead of both.
I also tried to block the communication between R1 and R3-R2 it didn't worked out, R1 is still able to traceroute it via R3.

**Is there any way to block the communication between R1 and R3 or how can I block R3[s1/1] interface?**

Comment: Please provide configurations and routing tables. Also, please be clear HOW you tried to do things and what the results were. As it is, we can only guess on all these things.

Comment: I made an end-to-end configuration using OSPF and tried to block the R3 using access-list and distribute-list still it is able to traceroute it.

Comment: This isn't helping at all. Please add details to your original question stating exactly *what* you did (the exact commands). We can't tell you what you did wrong if you're not telling us what you did or what configuration you've been using.

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to assign OSPF cost so that

No, that's not possible. Both your indicated paths include the subpath R1 -> ... -> R2 which you want to run in different directions. Since normal routing is based on the destination address and is individually decided on each hop, there's no way to modify link costs to come up with the intended result. Whether you use static routes or a routing protocol to distribute routes doesn't matter.

The only thing [*1] that would work is *policy-based routing* - that way you could route packets originating from R1 or from R5 in different directions .

Of course, that's not really useful in your scenario - no matter the link costs, using static or dynamic routes would result in a more efficient network. Routing packets *away* from the destination can't be efficient.

[*1] I'm ignoring techniques like separated routing domains here for simplicity.